# python how to read dictionary which has a name into a file

Tags: python

I have a file with a dictionary in it that looks like:

`statesname = {'Alabama' : ('AL', '4,779,736'), 'Alaska' : ('AK', '710,231')}`

How do I read this dictionary into another file? When I do it, it ends up as a string.

Comment: Why not just `import` it?

Answer (score 1):

In python 2 use `execfile()`:

```py
>>> execfile("statesname.py")
>>> statesname
{'Alabama': ('AL', '4,779,736'), 'Alaska': ('AK', '710,231')}
>>>
```

In python 3 you have few options:

- import may work:

```py
import statesname
```

[past.builtins](https://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html):

```py
from past.builtins import execfile

execfile("statesname.py")
```

or, after [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.0.html?highlight=execfile#builtins)

```py
fx=open("statesname.py", "r")
exec(open(fx).read())
```

or:

```py
exec(compile(open("statesname.py", "rb").read(), filename, 'exec'), globals, locals)
```

but this may cause unintended [consequences with namespaces](https://exceptionshub.com/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3.html), so you have to check.

Comment: `execfile` was removed in Python 3.0. For a bit of the reasons why, see for example https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-June/135087.html

Comment: I will edit it then. I mean, I didn't realise. It's because I used `past.builtins`.